# Updated and Cleaned World Railroads Data

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Does anybody have the updated and cleaned and connected world railroads network?

In a way that could be used for routing.

Answer (score 1):

Try OSM data http://download.geofabrik.de/. IMHO there is no better source of rails data.